# No value given for one or more required parameters adodb access error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to assign archival id in my database to the corresponding file number column through an Excel userform. It should find the largest alphanumeric string in the column, and increment it by 1 and assign that in the archival id column.
This is the VBA code for that:

```
Sub Archival()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
        Dim dbPath As String
        Dim qry As String
        Dim qry2 As String
        
        dbPath = "\\share.company.net@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\FileNumberandLDS\Shared Documents\General\NewDB.accdb"
        
        cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"
        
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
        qry = "SELECT * FROM FileNumbers WHERE [File_Number]= '" & ArchivalForm.txtFile.Value & "'"
        
        rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
        
        If ArchivalForm.cmbRetention.Value = "A" Then
            qry2 = "SELECT max(val(mid(Archival_id,3))) FROM FileNumbers WHERE [Archival_id] ALIKE 'A%'"
            rs.Open qry2, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
            newfile = "A-" & (rs.Fields(0) + 1)
        End If
            
        If ArchivalForm.cmbRetention.Value = "C" Then
            qry2 = "SELECT max(val(mid(Archival_id,3))) FROM FileNumbers WHERE [Archival_id] ALIKE 'C%'"
            rs.Open qry2, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
            newfile = "C-" & (rs.Fields(0) + 1)
        End If
        
        With rst
            .Fields("Archival_id").Value = newfile
            .Fields("Remarks").Value = ArchivalForm.txtRemarks.Value
            .Fields("Retention Category").Value = ArchivalForm.cmbRetention.Value
            .Fields("Archived By").Value = Application.UserName
            .Fields("Archived On").Value = Date
            .Update
        End With
        'cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO TheTable.....", , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
        'Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity", , adCmdText)
    rst.Close
    rs.Close
    cnn.Close
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    MsgBox ("The Archival id is " & newfile)
End Sub
```

I am getting error "No value given for one or more required" on the line:

```
rs.Open qry2, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

This is what my database looks like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8baZa.png

Comment: Try: `LIKE 'A*'`, `LIKE 'C*'`.

Comment: Nothing changed, it shows same error

Comment: Does connection work? Are you able to open recordset without filter criteria? What happens when there are no records meeting criteria and attempt to generate first Archival_ID?

Comment: Save prefix and sequence in separate fields and code to generate sequence will be simplified. Did you step debug? Is value pulled from recordset?

Comment: Connection works, I am using same connection code for multiple other things in project and everything works well

Comment: The issue was with underscore, I got through the error, but now I am stuck with Archival id generated as A- instead of A-12348 because A-12347 is the highest id in the database. All the other fields are populated as expected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an underscore in place of *space*:

```
qry2 = "SELECT max(val(mid([Archival id],3))) FROM FileNumbers WHERE [Archival id] ALIKE 'A%'"
```

Comment: An underscore is appropriate if field name actually has an underscore. I do see inconsistency in use of underscore: Archival_ID, File_Number, Retention Category, Archived By, Archived On. Advise not to use space in naming convention.

Comment: @June7: But, from the screen shot, it hasn't.

Comment: You were right, I got through the error. It was because of the underscore. Thanks a lot for finding this silly error. But I am still stuck because archival id being generated is A- instead of A-12348, I am not sure why. All the other fields are being populated as they should though.

Comment: Check the value of `rs.Fields(0)` or `rs.Fields(0).Value`. I guess it is _Null_.

Comment: But it shouldn't be null, there is multiple data in the column with format A-xxxxx